# Running python script in loop

Tags: python, loops

how can i run this code in loop?I want it to display me the Decibel Values once a second.Im not a programmer..

```
import nsrt_mk3_dev


nsrt = nsrt_mk3_dev.NsrtMk3Dev('COM4')
model = nsrt.read_model()


leq_level = nsrt.read_leq()
weighting = nsrt.read_weighting()
weighted_level = nsrt.read_level()

print (f'DecibelLevel: {leq_level:0.2f} dB, {weighting} value: {weighted_level:0.2f}')
```

Comment: `while True:` and `time.sleep` can help.

Answer (score 0):

Endless loop in python with condition to quit:

```
flag = True
while flag:
    run()
    if some_condition:
        flag = False
```

Comment: Sorry, im new to this, how can i inplement that in my code?

Comment: share code snippet https://codefile.io/f/z489Jj1SC4

Comment: what should i put here?  if YOUR_CONDITION_TO_ITERUPT: ? sorry im not a programmer

Comment: it's condition from endless loop when you should stop your program

Comment: yes i understood that, so what should i put for example when i press S key ?